# Civi Navigation Menu disappeared on upgrade form 5.20 to 5.24.2

Tags: upgrade, settings, paths

Upgrade of this drupal site appeared to go smoothly, but the navigation menu was missing. I reset menus & backend, cleared caches etc, switched asset caching off. Civi log showed nothing, nor did debug and trace.

Web console showed path errors. Tried overriding in civicrm.settings.php with little success UNTIL I changed $civicrm_root from an absolute path ('/var/web/domain/sites/all/modules/civicrm';) as specified in the files comments, to a relative path ('sites/all/modules/civicrm';)

Is this a newly introduced bug, or an error elsewhere in my configuration?